# Android EditText get nothing

Tags: android-studio

it's my EditText.

I run the app don't type anthing

when I sout gettext().toString

I got really nothing

not null or ""  why?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext"
        android:hint="@string/employeeHint1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text=""
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingStart="10dp" 
        />
```

this is for someone to type some info for me to do something 
I use hint, I don't want type anything to over the hint
and I have to make sure user to type something.

Comment: Here initially u r edittext is empty, u have to enter the text manually after that call  or print  ed_account.getText().toString()

Comment: your java code please

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this line

```
android:text="some text...."
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear, am sorry but please improve your english. And without the java code, am not sure i got your problem right, but try using this to check if the EditText is null:

```
EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```